# Identify the table dependencies graph from django models

Tags: python, django

I am using Django for my project and I came across a case where I need to identify the table dependencies by considering all the django models created in the project.

It should cover all types of relationships including

1. Many to Many
2. Many to One
3. One to One
4. Table inheritance

Currently, I am trying it using _meta attribute, I am including my approach here.

```
def build_table_dependecy_graph(models: [Model]) -> DependencyGraph:
    graph = DependencyGraph()
    for model in models:
       for dependency in _find_foreignkey_references(model):
           graph.add_dependency(dependency, _get_table_name(model))

       for dependency, table in _find_many_to_many_relations(model):
           graph.add_dependency(dependency, table)
    return graph


def _find_foreignkey_references(model: Model):
    return [_get_table_name(foreign_related_field.model)
            for field in model._meta.fields if hasattr(field, 'foreign_related_fields')
            for foreign_related_field in field.foreign_related_fields]

def _find_many_to_many_relations(model: Model):
    many_to_many_relationships = [field for field in model._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True) if
                              field.many_to_many and field.auto_created]
    for many_to_many_model in many_to_many_relationships:
        yield (_get_table_name(many_to_many_model.model), _get_table_name(many_to_many_model.through))
        yield (_get_table_name(many_to_many_model.related_model), _get_table_name(many_to_many_model.through))

def _get_table_name(model: Model) -> str:
    return model._meta.db_table
```

I don't know whether there is a better way of doing this in Django. Please help.